# good patterns for an enterprise git branching strategy?

Tags: git, github

I just created a new github repo and uploaded the codebase for an application.  A "master" branch exists by default.  What is a common and proper way to build out additional branches to support CICD?

For example, this repo should have a "develop" branch.  Should I simply git checkout -b from main as "develop" and then commit/push as-is?  Also, this repo should have a dedicated branch for the first release.  Is semantic versioning typically used for this like:

develop-[major].[minor].[patch]

Where this would be resolved for the first release as develop-1.0.0?  This seems like a logical way to do it to me but the domain of enterprise git branching strategies isn't my area of expertise

Comment: Why should your repo have a `develop` branch? Having both `develop` and `master` branches is likely to be associated with a popular branching strategy called "Git Flow", which generally is *not* used for CICD.

Answer (score 0):

I have worked on a number of Enterprise level projects and my personal preference is to always follow this basic outline:

- master branch - always matches what is currently released to
  production
- a release branch - v2.0.0 for example
- a build branch - v2.0.0.1 for example or v2.0.0.<epoch_timestamp> if
  you have lots of builds being executed which will happen if you have
  more than 4-5 developers working on the project.
- a feature branch - CR-123-SomeDescription containing fixes, new
  features, etc

As the work for a feature/fix branch is completed, it is merged into the build branch. The build branch is purposely there to make sure that all CI/CD build processes execute successfully, the unit test pass, etc. If unit test pass successfully, the build branch is merged into the release branch and deployed to the staging/testing server.

The release branch is tagged so it is easily identified instead of having branches named with the develop-[major].[minor].[patch] that you were suggesting. If you do follow that pattern, then someone has to clean up those branches at some point and it can get time consuming if you have lots of patches being applied.

The CI/CD builds get pushed first to a DEV instance so the developer can walk through his changes using the application, run additional Integration Tests, etc.
Once DEV TESTING has been completed, that same build is deployed to the TEST environment and turned over to the QA team.

Upon QA giving the blessing that everything is good, it then gets deployed to production and that release branch is merged into the master branch. Following this concept, master ALWAYS reflects current production, so if you need to do an emergency patch, you simply checkout master, apply your patch, add a new tag (v2.0.1.2 for example) and merge master back into the current release branch. Merging master back into the current release branch will force all current development to pull those changes back in before they can be merged forcing your developers to stay in-sync with changes that they may not be aware of.

Hope that helps.

Comment: sorry i'm not totally clear about your post. you're referring to a release branch named "v2.0.0"

but then you say:

"The release branch is tagged so it is easily identified instead of having branches named with the develop-[major].[minor].[patch] that you were suggesting."

so are you saying that the naming convention is fine but the current/latest release branch should also be tagged?

Comment: No - I would NOT use the naming convention you suggested.  The tagging is to identify the builds. For instance the v2.0.0 release may have multiple builds that occurred during the development stages, each one getting a tag such as v2.0.0.1, v2.0.0.2, v2.0.0.3, etc. The tags are useful to 1) identify what the "current" build is, and the tag will be retained when that branch v2.0.0 is merged into master.